# How does Facebook chat window work from a webpage point of view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am mostly interested in how they set the reply box to have a fixed position wrt to the screen while scrolling up through the messages, yet it docks nicely when the end of the messages is reached.

Do they only use CSS or is there some clever Javascript involved?

Comment: Have u tried looking at the source? :)

Comment: Yes, using Firebug. Still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: They use both CSS and scripts (but mostly scripts). Like the topmost `blueBar` that sticks at top of browser window instead of top of document. Disabling the relevant script will stop it from being sticky.